# Runtime parameters using jinjava

Tags: java, jinjava

Let's suppose I have a `Jinja` template and I want to see what are the parameters in this template that need to supplied during rendering to render the template. How to do this using `Jinjava` by Hubspot? I am using `Jinjava 2.1.10`. The functionality I am seeking is the same as `jinja2.meta.find_undeclared_variables` method in Python `Jinja2` package.